# Uninstall an Eclipse plugin when the "Uninstall..." button is disabled

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

Sometimes, for some reason, the "Uninstall" button is disabled in Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details (For example, after installing Aptana plugin, which forces the use of an older installer in Eclipse Galileo).

How is it possible to remove these plugins with "Uninstall" disabled ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go into "Installation History" tab (in Installation Details), choose a previous state of installation, and click "revert"

Comment: And what if one wants to remove just one plugin after a number of others have been installed, or if a bad one was installed at the same time as many good ones? I don't think reverting and then re-installing is the most appropriate action here.

Comment: Reverting was the only solution that worked for me. I ran the "check for updates" and ended up with a dependency issue between groovy and the rest. From 2020-06, it tried to update to 2020-09 and failed miserably. Or at least made me miserable for a day fixing the stupid issue.

Comment: revert failed for me

Answer (score 17):

Try run eclipse as administrator. It worked for me.

Comment: Same disabled for me as an admin, like it's not implemented.

Comment: +1 works for me, 
windows 8.1 has more strict permissions for stuff inside 'Program Files'

Comment: I had similar on MacOSX
`$ sudo /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse &` was what I needed

Comment: Worked nicely. Ctrl+Shift+IconClick opens the application as Admin, then remove everything you do not need and then back as normal user, the plugins are gone. :)