# After ADT update: Eclipse says it has two versions installed

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just updated my ADT to the latest version. Then I restarted Eclipse. From there on, every time I try to start Eclipse, it shows me the dialog below:

[image: Eclipse tells me to update ADT to version 22.6.2 or higher]

As far as I understand the dialog below, Eclipse tells me that it has two versions of ADT installed:
[image: Obviously Eclipse has two versions of ADT installed]

Why doesn't eclipse recognize that I have ADT 22.6.3 installed? Why it still shows ADT 21.0.0? How can I fix this? When I go to "check for updates", it doesn't find any more updates. I already thought of removing ADT and then installing it again, but the "uninstall" button for ADT is grayed out in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling and Reinstalling the ADT. Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details.

Comment: As I wrote in my posting, the "uninstall" button for ADT is grayed out.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478158/uninstall-an-eclipse-plugin-when-the-uninstall-button-is-disabled

Comment: Thanks, that helped. However I still wonder **why** Eclipse thought it had two versions installed.